# How to solve error Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'produk'?

Tags: flutter, error-handling

I got errors in debug console like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiFy5.png)

this my code error in API response.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> _getMoreData(int index) async {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      var url =
          "APIurl";
      print(url);
      final response = await dio.post(url,));
      List<produk> tList = [];
     for (int i = 0; i < response.data['data']['data'].length; i++) {
        tList.add(response.data['data']['data'][i]); 
      } // THIS MARK CODE ERRORS
   
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        users.addAll(tList);
        page++;
      });
    }
    return null;
  }
```

this my new model class.

[my new model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3reZ.png)

i updated the code like this
[updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iRgQ.png)

and i getting new error like
`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<produk>'`

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
Future<List<ProductModel>> fetch()async{

    String url = "";

    var response = await http.post((Uri.parse(url)));

    List temp = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['data'];

    debugPrint(temp[0]);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      return temp.map((e) => ProductModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    }else{
      throw Exception("error");
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks but, i triy this code i got  another errors "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' "

Comment: can you add the Json response in your post?

Comment: like this ??
i post in ur answer

Comment: No, the json response that you get from the api call. Add it to your original post.

Comment: no like this picture ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J69Rk.png

Comment: yeah use debugPrint(response.body); and post the result in your post

Comment: this updated code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSGAW.png

Comment: this result from response, can u help ?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEcE5.png

Comment: copy the Json, paste it and edit it in your post.  It's easy to point out the error.

and your updated code is still wrong. You're adding jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['data'] to List<produk> which is giving you unhandled exception as the decoded response you're getting is List<Map>.